# Typecasting int to char in printf() in C

Tags: c, casting

```
int *int_pointer = malloc(10);

*int_pointer = 53200;

printf("The integer at byte #0 is set to: %d \n", (char) *int_pointer);
```

RESULT: -48

So I was just trying this out to see what would happen and I got this really unexpected result.

Why -48? How did it even turn into negative?